# Dynamic text with angular

Tags: html, angularjs, text, bind

I am trying to make a dynamic text that is edible only for some of it, and the non edible is from a database or variables.

For example, if I have a variable kid's name = Adam, and my sentence is:

```
'Yesterday I was talking to Adam, He enjoyed the show as well'
```

Than I can change everything except 'Adam'. Multiple inputs fields and ng-binds is a brutal way to solve it any elegant idea? something like:

```
<p>Yesterday I spoke to {{ kid }}, and edit more stuff here</p>
```

And then I could immediately change the text in the browser.

Thank you

Comment: you want to change everything apart from Adam?

Comment: The question is unclear. Where is the text coming from which you want to change? Who is 'I' in your question? a user or you as in the programmer?

Comment: Not all come in easy way. You need to do some coding. At least you might need some directive.

Comment: @Pratik Yes so I can edit only some words within the sentence.

Comment: @0xc0de The text could be an html element it does not matter. the goal it to be able to edit only some of the text.

Comment: @iProgrammer Can you give me any starting points?

Comment: As you said already, multiple ng-binds and input fields.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" ng-model="beforeKid" />
<input type="text" ng-model="afterKid" />

<p><span>{{beforeKid}}</span><span>{{kid}}</span><span>{{afterKid}}</span></p>
```

How about this? Two inputs, to change the values before Kid's name and after. Your kid's name will be constant.

Comment: This is not a good solution in light of the fact that there are two inputs.
The goal is to edit some of the text within the sentence

Comment: You can't have an inner binding within another binding. So if you are ready to have your kid changed by the message you type, then you can go with one input. I will try and another solution, but I cant find any as of now.

Comment: No, the kid should staye untouched. Only if there was something like:
<input ng-model="sentence"></input> and then: 

$scope.sentence = '..... Adam ....'
$scope.sentence: { 'Adam': 'untouched' }

Comment: I don't think Angular provides that as a feature. And it doesn't make sense too.